# log4net vs. Nlog

Tags: log4net, nlog

Anyone have experience for both?  How do they stack up against each other?

We are planning on using one of them for logging in an enterprise application.

References:

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

[nlog](http://www.nlog-project.org/)

EDIT: We have no existing dependencies to either nlog or log4net.

Comment: Good for you, but some people may need the ability to turn logging on/off dynamically, to use different log levels, to automatically delete old log data, etc.

Comment: It should be noted that the Log4Net documentation is terrible.

Comment: You should give ReflectInsight a try. Much more powerful then both http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/

Comment: @code5 ReflectInsight viewer is commercial (free until March 2014), $299 after 2013-Jul-01.

Answer (score 383):

I was recently tasked to "prototype up some loggin'" for an upcoming project.  I didn't have any logging framework experience.  I researched, ran through tutorials, made toy apps, etc. on Log4Net, NLog, and Enterprise Library for a few days.  Came back 3-4 weeks later and put them together into a cohesive demo.  Hopefully some of this is useful to you.

My recommendation for our project is this:

1. Use a logging facade (e.g. [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sf.net/), [SimpleLoggingFacade](https://slf.codeplex.com/)) to avoid direct dependencies.
2. If we end up using Enterprise Library for other facilities, then use it for Logging, too.
3. If we end up using something with a dependency on Log4Net, use Log4Net.
4. If none of the above, use NLog. Which I'd prefer.

That's based on these findings (opinions!):

- All 3 frameworks are capable and can do some sophisticated things.  We want a quality solution, but frankly don't need ultra high performance or 60 types of event sinks.
- All 3 have very similar basic concepts.
- Each has its own cool tricks, like really advanced routing, or dynamic log filenames, file truncating, etc.
- All 3 are pretty well documented in their own way.
- For a complete newb like me, they were all a little awkward initially.  No drastic differences here for the basics.  I got over it.
- When revisiting things a few weeks later, NLog was *clearly* the easiest to resume.  I needed very little brush up on it.  With Log4Net, I had to revisit a few online examples to get going.  With EntLib, I gave up and did the tutorials all over again from scratch - I was totally lost.
- I couldn't figure out how to get EntLib to do some things like log to the database.  It might be easy, but it was beyond my time limit.
- Log4Net and NLog have a small in-code footprint.  EntLib is spammy, but I'd use a facade over it anyway.
- I accidentally mis-configured EntLib and it told me at run time.  Log4Net didn't.  I didn't have an accidental mis-config with NLog.
- EntLib comes with a nice looking app.config editor, which you 100% need.  NLog has a config file schema so you get "intellisense".  Log4Net comes with nada.

So obviously I like NLog so far.  Not enough to use it in spite of having another solution available, though.

Comment: +1 on recommending building a Facade for true Seperation of Concerns (SoC), or so you don't polute your domain.

Comment: The facade only works if you can do it without breaking diagnostic values that are dependent on the call stack, etc. I've seen a lot of facades that break these essential diagnostic features that ended up doing more harm that good...

Comment: Have you looked back at EntLib now that you have more experience with logging? I'm new to logging platforms and want to make sure I go with the most solid solution first if possible.

Comment: This project was postponed, so I have no new knowledge, sorry.  Our new architect is sponsoring EntLib to replace our persistence, so it will probably be our logger, too.  In your case - I don't know your situ or what you need when you say "solid".  All 3 are sufficient for basic corporate .NET apps.  They more differentiate on ease of setup, ease of use, flat-out performance, options, and sellability.  EntLib will make a fine solution if you don't mind the syntax. IMO, coming up with your logging strategy/policy will be the bigger deal.

Comment: Log4Net does not yet support the Client Profiles of .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4, because it references System.Web. Just wanted to point that out, although it's actually closely related to 'with a dependency on Log4Net, use Log4Net.'

Comment: NLog is actively supported (http://nlog-project.org/download) while Log4Net hasn't been updated since version 1.2.10 was published published April 19, 2006 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET/fixforversion/11128)

Comment: Log4Net gets confused with IPv4 and IPv6 on newer Windows machines. Can't resolve localhost properly. Several unofficial patches are floating around. See for example http://devva.net/blog/post/log4net-UdpAppender-on-IPv6-(Windows-2008-Vista-or-7).aspx

Comment: If you have a dependency on a library using log4net and want to use NLog instead (or vice-versa), it's fairly straightforward to write and configure a custom Appender class to bridge the two.

Comment: I wanted to add that Log4Net was recently updated to 1.2.11, and now adds support for .NET 4.0 as well as the client profiles of .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0.

Comment: I noticed RavenDB uses Nlog. Ayenede isn't renowned for choosing bad code & frameworks. Remeber Nhibernate has been around a long time & (probably) predates Nlog. Also if you're using Raven then obviously Nlog is already there. If you're planning on using Raven then get some Nlog practice in. Without being too sheeplish about it I'm inclined to follow Ayende's lead on pretty-much anything .NET related.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail why using a 'facade' is useful? What is a 'logging facade' anyway?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher - Sorry, I don't watch this question much anymore. Your comment would be a great question for discussion elsewhere! For me, at the time, the "facade" would have been a) to streamline EntLib's verbose method calls and b) so we could switch out loggers without changing code all across the app. The latter was a concern for due to frequent technical leadership turnover and associated changes in our tech stack direction. FWIW, I would have made a very simple, ~4 function custom interface and not have used the logging interface libraries Pat recommended (not to diss them).

Comment: You can use System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(...) in bundle with NLog.NLogTraceListener. This will give you flexibility and power of logger library. Helpful when you ship some component to a customer that uses other logger.

Answer (score 158):

A key consideration that hasn't been much discussed is support and updates.

[**Log4Net hasn't been updated since version 1.2.10 was published April 19, 2006**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET/fixforversion/11128).

In contrast, NLog has been actively supported since 2006 will soon release [**NLog 2.0 supporting many platforms that didn't exist when log4net was last updated**](http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/26/nlog-2-0-beta-1-has-been-released.html) such as:

- NET Framework 2.0 SP1 and above, 3.5 & 4.0 (Client and Extended profiles)
- Silverlight 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
- .NET Compact Framework 2.0, 3.5
- Mono 2.x profile

Comment: But does it need updating? If it ain't broken, don't fix it?

Comment: It *is* broken:
* Messes up ip address resolution between IPv4/IPv6 for localhost on Vista and Win7 (several unofficial patches are floating around)
* Doesn't compile in .Net 4.0 Client Profile

Comment: Yes, it needs updating. It requires you to write code to extend AdoNetAppender to use a connection name already configured, vs hardcoding the string. This has been a long requested feature. The thing is stable, but considered dead until we see evidence of life.

Comment: There appears to be a .NET 4.0 version in the works for Log4Net.

Comment: NLog Beta 2 doesn't work on mono and .Net 3.5 (http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/5305 reported on Oct 15 2010)

Comment: NLog 2 was released a month ago with this support, and log4net still has the issue.  I also can't find any info on when log4net 1.2.11 is going to be released (which will support .Net 4.0).  Edit: Seems like they still don't have a timeline, though it is getting closer: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/201108.mbox/%3C8739gynifc.fsf@v35516.1blu.de%3E

Comment: [log4net has launched v1.2.11 on October 2011](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET). I think this answer is obsolete now.

Comment: Actually, this answer was still valuable to me. I'm in the process of choosing a logger, and this answer tells us that log4net has been updated once in the last half decade, while NLog is a more active project.

Comment: Since NLog 2.0 has been released nothing happens with it too. Their web site indicates they are actively seeking someone to take over the whole project. So I guess you can't really call NLog being "more active".

Comment: log4net has 103 issues (5 critical, 56 major): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel

Comment: For fun, Google Trends still thinks log4net is in the lead -- http://www.google.ca/trends/explore#q=log4net%2C%20%20NLog&cmpt=q

Comment: Probably fairer to link to the log4net [changelog](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:changelog-panel), rather than a particular release. There have been 3 releases since 1.2.10, with 1.2.13 just over a year ago.

Answer (score 97):

Having had an experience with both frameworks recently, I thought I can share my views on each frameworks.

I was asked to evaluate the logging frameworks for an existing web application, I narrowed down my choices to NLog (v2.0) and log4net (v1.2.11) after going through various online forums. Here are my findings:

1. Setting/starting up with NLog is dead easy. You go through the Getting started tutorial on their website and you are done. You get a fair idea, how thing might be with nlog. Config file is so intuitive that anyone can understand the config. For example: if you want to set the internal logging on, you set the flag in Nlog config file's header node, which is where you would expect it to be. In log4net, you set different flags in web.config's appSettings section.
2. In log4net, internal logging doesnt output timestamp which is annoying. In Nlog, you get a nice log with timestamps. I found it very useful in my evaluations.
3. Filters in log4net - You better check my this question - [log4net filter - how to write AND filter to ignore log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8604041/984438) and if you find an answer/solution for this, please let me know. 
   I understand, there is a workaround for this question, as you can write your own custom filter. But something which is not easily available in log4net.
4. Performance - I logged around 3000 log messages to database using a stored procedure. I used simple for loop (int i=0; i<3000; i++... to log the same message 3000 times. For the writes: log4net AdoAppender took almost double the time than NLog.
5. Log4net doesnt support asynchronous appender.

It was sufficient comparison for me to choose NLog as the logging framework. :)

Comment: log4net's internal debugging logs: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging.html

Answer (score 36):

For anyone getting to this thread late, you may want to take a look back at the .Net Base Class Library (BCL).  Many people missed the changes between .Net 1.1 and .Net 2.0 when the **TraceSource** class was introduced (circa 2005).

Using the TraceSource is analagous to other logging frameworks, with granular control of logging, configuration in app.config/web.config, and programmatic access - without the overhead of the enterprise application block.

- [.Net BCL Team Blog: Intro to Tracing - Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396431.aspx) *(Look at Part II a,b,c as well)*

There are also a number of comparisons floating around: "log4net vs TraceSource"

Comment: EntLib Is extending TraceSource

Answer (score 34):

For us, the key difference is in overall perf...

Have a look at `Logger.IsDebugEnabled` in NLog versus Log4Net, from our tests, NLog has less overhead and that's what we are after (low-latency stuff).

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 25):

First look at the rest of your stack.

If you are using NHibernate, it utilizes Log4Net directly.
Other frameworks might have other specific loggers they need.

Other than that: both work fine.

I've settled on Log4Net myself.  It can be a pain to configure, and if it isn't configured correctly it is a pain to figure out what went wrong.  But you can make it do almost anything you would want from a logger.

If you don't have a standing issue with Log4Net, here is an article I wrote on how to get started with it:
http://elegantcode.com/2007/12/07/getting-started-with-log4net/

Comment: @greg: Note that in NHibernate v3 the dependency on log4net is thankfully removed - it's pluggable so you can use NLog if you wish.

Comment: NLog is an equal pain to configure/figure out what's wrong too. At least with log4net you can find documentation and or google for issues.

Comment: Good point on taking the rest of your stack into consideration, I cannot say that is a concern I would have considered off the top of my head. While it looks like NHibernate is no longer an example for this scenario, Sitecore provides a contemporary example of this, since it uses Log4Net internally. Sitecore is pretty extensible, so you could use whatever you prefer to log, but that is far more complex than editing the site's web.config to add your own loggers

Answer (score 16):

Well .. I used Enterprise library for database logging tasks
and now I switched to NLog due to performance bottleneck.

some comparison info :

http://pauliusraila.blogspot.com/2010/10/solving-database-logging-bottlenecks.html

Answer (score 14):

I echo the above and do prefer nLog. Entlib is needlessly bloated.

Re:Log4net One thing that ALWAYS gets me with log4net is forgetting to add the following to the global.asax to init the component:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Answer (score 13):

If you go [here](http://www.dotnetlogging.com/comparison/) you can find a comprehensive matrix that includes both the NLog and Log4Net libs as well as Enterprise Lib and other products.

Somebody could argue that the matrix is done in a way to underline the features of the only commercial lib present in the matrix. I think it's true but it was useful anyway to drive my choice versus NLog.

Regards

Comment: Looking at that matrix it seems considerably out of date with respect to at least The Object Guy's framework, which is a commercial competitor.

Answer (score 9):

As I noticed, log4net locks their output files the whole time application is running, so you can't delete them. Otherwise they are similar.

So I prefer NLog.

Comment: Add <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" /> to your fileappender config to prevent this (mentioned on the log4net examples page here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

Answer (score 9):

Shameless plug for an open source project I run, but given the lively discussion about which .NET logging framework is more active I thought I'd post an obligatory link to [Serilog](http://serilog.net).

To use within an application, Serilog is similar to (and draws heavily on) log4net. Unlike other .NET logging options, however, Serilog is about preserving the structure of log events for offline analysis. When you write:

```
Log.Information("The answer is {Answer}", 42);
```

Most logging libraries immediately render the message into a string. Serilog can do that too, but it preserves the `{ Answer: 42 }` property so that later on, using one of a number of NoSQL data stores, you can properly query events based on the value of `Answer`.

We're close to a 1.0 and support all of the modern (.NET 4.5, Windows Store and Windows Phone 8) platforms.

Comment: But the question is: Does it support Mono? ;) It looks promising (and I love the thread and needle logo) but couldn't find any information on whether it supports Mono or not.

Comment: Good question :) ... yes, we have users on Mono - I'm not sure if they're using the .NET 4.5 or 4.0 build of Serilog, but if you hit any issues we'll help out.

Comment: .NET 4.5 support got me, downloading and trying out your solution right now

Answer (score 8):

I second NLog too because it works with unmanaged code too.
I suppose it could be possibe to use log4net and log4cxx together, but NLog handles both managed and unmanaged code out of the box.

I also looked at [Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sf.net/), a facade that makes abstraction of the logging api, it supports log4net, NLog and Entreprise Library. I don't think i'll use it, but i like how they use lambdas to improve performance when logging is disabled (a feature shared with NLog and probably others).

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider [Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=pandp.50).aspx). It comes with nice designer.

Comment: Enables you to configure it visually as opposed to hand crafting XML. Depends on your taste...

Comment: The idea of using visual tools for such a thing is not a good thing.

Comment: Maybe not a good thing, but for EntLib visual configurator is necessary. Writing configuration manually is practically impossible, it's too complicated (You know, it's from Microsoft).

Comment: Even if someone did not like a visual designer, why downvote! :o

Comment: EntLib does logging synchronously, it can essentially hit performance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general consensus is that nlog is a bit easier to configure and use. Both are quite capable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, [SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/) beats both NLog and log4net.

Its extremely easy to use, documentation is great, and you can **view and filter previously logged messages** with their interactive log viewer, which is a huge real world advantage.

One thing I like is the tabbed views of data, like the browser tabs in Chrome. Each tab can provide a different filtered view of the log.

Comment: It is a paid product. NLog & Log4Net are free.