# High Performance Logging in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, logging

What is the best direction to go if we are logging every user action in a web application that could potentially have 20K users on at the same time?  Should we build a list cache of the log data, and persist it to the database after a certain amount of time or threshold?  Are there any good libraries or techniques that can do this?

Comment: — [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should we build a list cache of the log data, and persist it to the database after a certain amount of time or threshold

If you cache and you crash, goodbye logs.

> Are there any good libraries or techniques that can do this?

It is best to use a flexible logging mechanism that you can turn on and filter at will, that has ultra high performance when disabled.

I recommend using an existing library.  You *don't* want bugs in your logging to mask bugs in production.

[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) (and other such logging libraries) can be used to do this fairly easily.  It is designed to suit the needs of a large range of projects, and has techniques that allow you to have a very low performance impact when you have disabled it.  It also has built-in multi-threaded/asynchronous logging support.

That being said, there are a *lot* of reasonable quality .Net logging libraries out there.  Check out this question for some quality comparison opinions (more libraries are represented than the title suggests): [log4net vs. Nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710863/log4net-vs-nlog)