# log4net filter - how to write AND filter to ignore log messages

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-filter

I am struggling to write an AND conditional filter in log4net. Had it been nLog, I could have written it this way:

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" xsi:type="NLogLoggerRule" writeTo="FooLogger" >
  <filters>
    <when condition="equals('${event-context:item=UserID}', 'TESTUSER') 
                 and equals('${event-context:item=URL}','/foo/foobar.aspx')" 
          action="Ignore" />
  </filters>
</logger>
```

I am not sure how to write the same filter in log4net. I have been so far successful, in writing a single condition:

```xml
<appender>
   ....
   <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="URL" />
      <stringToMatch value="/foo/foobar.aspx" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
   </filter>
</appender>
```

How can I write AND conditions using log4net filters? Please help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A custom filter supporting AND conditions. This class exposes Filter property so existing log4net filters can be used here and also one can have nested AND conditions if required.

```cs
public class AndFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    private bool acceptOnMatch;
    private readonly IList<IFilter> filters = new List<IFilter>();

    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");

        foreach(IFilter filter in filters)
        {
            if (filter.Decide(loggingEvent) != FilterDecision.Accept)
                return FilterDecision.Neutral; // one of the filter has failed
        }

        // All conditions are true
        if(acceptOnMatch)
            return FilterDecision.Accept;
        else
            return FilterDecision.Deny;
    }

    public IFilter Filter 
    { 
        set { filters.Add(value); }
    }

    public bool AcceptOnMatch
    {
        get { return acceptOnMatch;}
        set { acceptOnMatch = value;}
    }
}
```

Config:

```xml
<filter type="Namespace.AndFilter, Assembly">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
    <key value="URL" />
    <stringToMatch value="/foo/foobar.aspx" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
    <key value="UserID" />
    <stringToMatch value="TESTUSER" />
  </filter>
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

Comment: Yeah, I also came up with compound filter (like as your AddFilter), but didn't figured how to add inner filters via config. That is really cool trick :)
public IFilter Filter { set { filters.Add(value); } }

Comment: Thanks, helped. It's pity that this isn't a standard log4net feature.

Comment: I changed "Namespace" to the one where I put the AndFilter code and I got an error in the log4net debug trace "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly' or one of its dependencies" - what should I change "Assembly" to? If the name of my project is MSC and it creates a MSC.dll would it be "MSC" (but this didn't work)

Comment: Still a very useful bit of code even now.

Answer (score 9):

You can create custom filter for your business needs:

```cs
public class UserRequestFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");

        string userId = (string)loggingEvent.Properties["UserId"];
        string url = (string)loggingEvent.Properties["Url"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
            return FilterDecision.Neutral;

        if (UserId.Equals(userId) && Url.Equals(url, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return AcceptOnMatch ? FilterDecision.Accept : FilterDecision.Deny;

        return FilterDecision.Neutral;
    }

    public bool AcceptOnMatch { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration will look like this:

```xml
<filter type="Namespace.UserRequestFilter, Assembly">
  <userId value="TESTUSER"/>
  <url value="/foo/foobar.aspx"/>
  <acceptOnMatch value="true"/>
</filter>
```

Also you can create compound filter, but I didn't find way to use it in configuration. Looks like it could be attached only programmatically (which is useless ^_^):

```cs
IAppenderAttachable logger = (IAppenderAttachable)_log.Logger;
AppenderSkeleton appender = (AppenderSkeleton)logger.GetAppender("appenderName");
CompoundFilter compoundFilter = new CompoundFilter();
compoundFilter.AddFilter(new PropertyFilter() { Key = "UserId", StringToMatch = "TEST" });
compoundFilter.AddFilter(new PropertyFilter() { Key = "Url", StringToMatch = @"/foo/foobar.aspx" });
appender.AddFilter(compoundFilter);
logger.AddAppender(appender);
```

[UPDATE]

Here is trick that you can use - create filter, which will check all filters down the filters chain:

```cs
public class DenyAllSubsequentFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        IFilter nextFilter = Next;
        if (nextFilter == null)
            return FilterDecision.Accept;

        while (nextFilter != null)
        {
            if (nextFilter.Decide(loggingEvent) != FilterDecision.Deny)
                return FilterDecision.Accept;

            nextFilter = nextFilter.Next;
        }

        return FilterDecision.Deny;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```xml
<filter type="Namespace.DenyAllSubsequentFilter, Assembly"/>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
  <key value="UserId" />
  <stringToMatch value="TEST" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
  <key value="Url" />
  <stringToMatch value="/foo/foobar.aspx" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

This filter will deny logging message if all subsequent filters will deny it.

Comment: Thanks @lazyberezovsky! Actually, I was looking for built-in filter which supports AND conditions. But, after realising that log4net doesn't support one, I wrote a custom AndFilter which worked for us. I will share code for benefit of others: