# Log4Net - how to properly use PropertyFilter

Tags: log4net

Ok, here's the appender:

```
<appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="debug.log" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
    <Key value="ApplicationName" />
    <StringToMatch value="Test Application" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="DEBUG" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="Date:%date Thread:[%thread] Level:%-5level Logger:%logger - ApplicationName:%property{ApplicationName}; Message:%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Now, it seems this would check the ThreadContext.Properties["ApplicationName"] string and if it finds 'Test Application' it would log.

Well, it's logging everything, even if ApplicationName="DoNotLog".

Now, I will freely admit this may be due to the way I'm (attempting) to use Log4Net - I need to expose it to COM, so I've wrapped up a singleton Log4Net instance, and call this from COM:

```
public void LogDebug(LogCodeSource codeSource, LogExecutionSource execSource, object message, Exception exception = null)
    {
        // Add the thread context properties for appender filtering purposes
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ApplicationName"] = codeSource.ApplicationName;
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ComponentName"] = codeSource.ComponentName;
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["MethodName"] = codeSource.MethodName;
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ClientMachineName"] = execSource.ClientMachineName;
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["ServerMachineName"] = execSource.ServerMachineName;
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["UserName"] = execSource.UserName;

        if (exception == null)
        {
            LoggerContext.GetInstance.MainLogger.Debug(message);
        }
        else
        {
            LoggerContext.GetInstance.MainLogger.Debug(message, exception);
        }
    }
```

In my tests, if I call:

```
var logger = new MyLogger();

logger.LogDebug(new LogCodeSource { ApplicationName = "Test Application", ComponentName = "Test component", MethodName = "Test method" }, new LogExecutionSource { ClientMachineName = "Test client", ServerMachineName = "Test server", UserName = "Test user" }, "Test message");
logger.LogDebug(new LogCodeSource { ApplicationName = "DoNotLog", ComponentName = "Test component", MethodName = "Test method" }, new LogExecutionSource { ClientMachineName = "Test client", ServerMachineName = "Test server", UserName = "Test user" }, "Test message");
```

In root, I've tried:

```
<root>
  <appender-ref ref="DebugFileAppender" />
</root>
```

As well as:

```
<logger name="MyLogger">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

Both logs are showing up in my debug.log file.

Any idea why the property filter isn't preventing DoNotLog from going to debug.log?

Here's what I'm seeing in the log:

```
Date:2015-12-31 11:11:00,928 Thread:[14] Level:DEBUG Logger:MyLogger - ApplicationName:Test Application; Message:Test message
Date:2015-12-31 11:11:00,942 Thread:[14] Level:DEBUG Logger:MyLogger - ApplicationName:DoNotLog; Message:Test message
```

Comment: Have you tried using _just_ that `<filter>` definition?  I have a feeling if you have multiple filters stacked up like that, if _any_ of them pass, it will be logged.  Been a while since I looked though, so can't remember the exact details.  Might be more about it falling through from one to another...

Comment: Hmm... that worked.  So does Log4Net not have a way to prevent cascading through all the filters?

Or do I need to just specify <logger name><level value><appender-ref> for each level?

Comment: Thinking a bit more, I _think_ that each filter can return 3 things.  Something along the lines of "Log" -> will be logged.  "Deny" -> won't be logged, will stop processing.  "Meh" -> will continue with the next filter.  Looks like at the moment your property filter is returning "Meh".  Whether there's another option you can pass to it to change that to "Deny" I'm not sure, I'd have to start digging in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is an AND filter since you want to log all message where `ApplicationName` matches a particular name AND the level is `DEBUG`. Unfortunately log4net doesn't ship AND filters out of the box however [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8859037/220986) details how to implement one.

Answer (score 1):

Property filter are also available when using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstraction instead if log4Net directly.

Example:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("YourPropertyKey", "YourPropertyValue") }))
{
    _logger.LogDebug("My special log with context property set");
}
```

Then in the config an appender has to be setup for the property and key.
Note there is rexexToMatch in oder to stringToMacth if you want to allow multiple values to a key.

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="property_logger" />
  </root>
  <appender name="property_logger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs/my_service.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="-yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <Key value="YourPropertyKey" />
      <StringToMatch value="YourPropertyValue" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level %.50logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```