# log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter is not working

Tags: c#, log4net, logentries

I am new to logenteries working on `log4net` filter i have tried remaining filters like "level range,`stringtomatch`,`LoggerMatchFilter`" all are working fine however property filter is not working . I have tried different solutions also it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

**code:**

```
public class CustomFilter : FilterSkeleton
{
    private bool acceptOnMatch;
    private readonly IList<IFilter> filters = new List<IFilter>();

    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");

        foreach (IFilter filter in filters)
        {
            if (filter.Decide(loggingEvent) != FilterDecision.Accept)
                return FilterDecision.Neutral; // one of the filter has failed
        }

        // All conditions are true
        if (acceptOnMatch)
            return FilterDecision.Accept;
        else
            return FilterDecision.Deny;
    }

    public IFilter Filter
    {
        set { filters.Add(value); }
    }

    public bool AcceptOnMatch
    {
        get { return acceptOnMatch; }
        set { acceptOnMatch = value; }
    }

}
```

I have seen this solution in [log4net filter - how to write AND filter to ignore log messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604041/log4net-filter-how-to-write-and-filter-to-ignore-log-messages/8859037#8859037) but for me filters not adding to **interface** . i didn't get whether **filters** are added directly or not ? In **loggingevent** i am passing the data in **message** property but the i don't know to how to add the into properties can any one please guide me and i don't know how to call this function.

**Webconfig :**

```
   <filter type="Namespace.CustomFilter, Assembly">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="firstname" />
      <stringToMatch value="1234" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="address" />
      <stringToMatch value="abcdf" />
    </filter>
    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
  </filter>
```

I have missed some where please help me out from it . I am struggling from past few hours.

**Update:**

```
    public string logFilter()
     {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(
            System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
           );

        var ReferenceID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var firstname = "1234";
        var address ="abcdf";
        var sno = "12";

        Log.InfoFormat("firstname {0}-{1}", firstname, ReferenceID);

        Log.InfoFormat("address {0}-{1}", address, ReferenceID);

        Log.InfoFormat("sno {0}-{1}", sno, ReferenceID);

        return ReferenceID;
    }
```

Here **decide()** function overide from **filterskelton** but property filter is not applying it able to read the details from **webconfig** but it can't filter the log message is there anything which i missed in it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if one of the filters returns FilterDecision.Neutral then log message will be logged. Therefor you need to check that message goes through all filters together

```
            public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
            {
                if (loggingEvent == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");

                if (filters.All(x => x.Decide(loggingEvent) != FilterDecision.Accept))
                {
                    return FilterDecision.Neutral;
                }

                // All conditions are true
                if (acceptOnMatch)
                    return FilterDecision.Accept;
                else
                    return FilterDecision.Deny;
            }
```

**UPDATE**:
my log4net config looks like that :

```
 <filter type="MyApp.CustomFilter, MyApp">
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
              <key value="firstname" />
              <stringToMatch value="1234" />
            </filter>
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
              <key value="address" />
              <stringToMatch value="abcdf" />
            </filter>
            <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
          </filter>
        </appender>
```

the sample how to check logging

```
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["firstname"] = "123";
        Log.Info("123");
    });

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["firstname"] = "1234";
        Log.Info("1234");
    });

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["address"] = "abcdf";
        Log.Info("abcdf");
    });
```

Comment: **loggingEvent** is null. How to assign the data to **LoggingEvent** . To which property I have to assign the data in **LoggingEvent** and filters also null.

Comment: i would like to clarify ,  <filter type="Namespace.CustomFilter, Assembly">, Namespace and Assembly you use  as place holder ? it is not a real code snap from your project

Comment: In the place of **NameSpace** i kept the namespace of the **CustomFilter**  in my code.

Comment: how about Assembly? use assembly name instead of place holder as well

Comment: From web config filters are reading but property filter is not applying to the log message.