# How to write a message to log file or console using extension method

Tags: c#, logging, console, console.writeline

here's my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (from d in new DirectoryInfo("E:\\")
    .GetDirectories() select d.Name)
             .WriteToConsole(Logger.WriteToLog , true);
            //    .WriteToConsole(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}

public static class Logger
{
    public static void WriteToLog(dynamic data)
    {
        string filePath = string.Format("{0}\\log.txt", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        var stream = File.Create(filePath);
        stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(data));
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();
    }
}

public static class WriteExtensions
{
    public static void WriteToConsole<T1>(this IEnumerable<T1> data , Action<T1> action, bool carelist = false)
    {
        if (carelist)
        {
            // all i want is to invoke action by sending data rather than
    // one by one
            return;
        }
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            action.Invoke(item);
        }
    }
}
```

problem is we can write to console line by line..but for writing to file i want to put all at once .. any help.. thanks

Comment: You have a function `WriteToConsole` that does not write to console. It's a little confusing. Also, is there a reason to use actions and extension methods? Why not do it some normal way?

Comment: 8th line commented ... uncommenting will write to console..

Comment: Your desire is to replace one line of code. My question is why? Why is it necessary to replace only one line of code? Why not replacing several lines?

Comment: Action handler will tackle writing logs at different areas..like db,file,console etc.... option to where have to write will come from db..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logging requirements are revealing to be complex. Therefore I suggest already existing [logging frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/710863/395718). They have functionalities that you need, but maybe don't yet realize that you need them. Logging to console and log file are supported, and can be enabled in configuration file, instead of in code directly. Also logging to several targets at the same time. Also filtering based on severity of the log. Also rollover to another file when date changes, or file grows over the limit.